# Вертикальное выравнивание элемента по центру в Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
В Twitter Bootstrap элемент не выравнивается вертикально (по центру) внутри блока.

Код HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <p>выравниваемый элемент</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
height: 40px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Без использования данного фреймворка, все работает корректно.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд самый лучший способ ставить *display: table;* родительскому элементу
а элементу внутри  display: *table-cell; vertical-align: middle;* .
Вот и рабочий пример:

```css
#parent {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
  background:#e0e0e0;
  height:60px;
}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы можете создать отличный ответ, приведя из этой статьи примеры решения проблемы, указанной в вопросе. Ссылку на материал можно привести, как источник. Ответы, содержащие только ссылку, через некоторое время могут превратиться в бесполезные за счёт изменения содержимого, доступного по этой ссылке. Более того, не все пользователи этого сайта в достаточной мере знакомы с английским языком, что уменьшает полезность вашего ответа

Answer (score 1):

Проблема стара как мир и я сам от неё мучусь иногда.
Поробуйте добавить line-height:40px;

Comment: Спасибо.

Проблема решилась Padding'ом. Bootstrap все-равно их "проглатывает".
line-height не вариант, так как при уменьшении экрана, отступы становятся слишком большими.

Answer (score 0):

*vertical-align* касается строки или ячейки таблицы (аналог – блок с "display: table-cell;"),

а не отступа её базовой линии внутри родительского блока

в *bootstrap* лучше всего:

```
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
```

(не работает, если у родителя  "display: table;")

Comment: Да вы некрофил друг мой :)

Comment: не угадали: я любитель вечности...

Answer (score 0):

```
.elem{
    display:flex
    align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: сами знаете кто в своих старых версиях (младше 11) не поймет это