# Как выровнять ссылку по центру в ячейке таблицы HTML

Tags: html, css, выравнивание, таблицы, табличная-верстка

Не могу понять как центрировать по вертикали и горизонтали текст ссылки, когда ячейке присвоено `display: block`.

```css
td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 75px;
  outline: 1px solid #7d7f7d;
  background: #999999 repeat;
}

td a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.google.ru/">Starting bid</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Попробуйте text-align:center; (по вертикали)  или воспользуйтесь css фреймворком Bootstrap - там есть класс для выравнивания текста в ячейке.

Comment: К сожалению, ваш способ не помогает...

Comment: попробуйте этот вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145856/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Можно изменить display:block, на display:flex и добавить еще одно свойство align-items:center;

Answer (score 2):

Решение найдено, нужно использовать `line-height:`.

```css
td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 75px;
  outline: 1px solid #7d7f7d;
  background: #999999 repeat;
}

a {
  color: #080F0F;
  line-height: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.google.ru/">Starting bid</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще `padding-top` и `padding-bottom` проставить чтобы выровнять. Например, высота ячейки `75px`, а размер шрифта `15px`, тогда выставляем у ячейки `padding-top` и `padding-bottom` по `30px` (чтобы в сумме было `30 + 30 + 15 = 75`). Тогда текст окажется по середине.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать flexbox для ссылки (`display: flex`). Текст ссылки тогда становится анонимным дочерним элементом flex-контейнера. В данном случае:

```css
td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 75px;
  outline: 1px solid #7d7f7d;
  background: #999999 repeat;
}

td a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* выравнивание по вертикали */
  justify-content: center; /* выравнивание по горизонтали */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.google.ru/">Starting bid</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```